# What are the inner workings of the post-increment operator?

Tags: programming-languages

I want to know about the inner functionality to execute post-increment or post-decrement operations in any programming language, such as java or c++.

I mean, how can something (function,method...) return a value and then perform operations on it afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite accurate to say that the post-increment/decrement operators operate on the value after returning it. The semantics of these operators, as they're defined in Java, C++ and probably all other languages that have such operators, are that they modify the value and then return the old value.

We could define a C++ function that exactly mimics the behavior of `++`<sup>1</sup> like this:

```
int post_inc(int& x) {
    int old_x = x;
    x = x + 1;
    return old_x;
}
```

In terms of the generated assembly, the most straight-forward way to implement postincrement (assuming the variable resides in a register) is to copy it into a second register, increment the first register, and then use the second register in whichever expression the `x++` was used in. If necessary the variable is read from memory into the first register at the beginning and written from the first register back into memory after the increment.

In many cases optimizing compilers will then re-arrange the code to just use one a single register, which is incremented after the expression (but that's not possible in all cases - for example it wouldn't work if the variable itself is used in the same expression (barring undefined behavior in C or C++)).

In terms of Java bytecode the implementation is: push the current value of the variable onto the stack, increment the variable (without touching the stack), then evaluate the expression that used `x++`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Minus undefined behavior because function calls introduce a sequence point